# Hive partitions on tables

Tags: hadoop, partitioning, hiveql

when we partition a table the columns on which the table is being partitioned are not mentioned in the create statement and separately used in the partitioned by.What is the reason behind this.

```
CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION DATA   (
    userid             BIGINT,
    First_Name        STRING,
    Last_Name         STRING,
    address1           STRING,
    address2           STRING,
    city               STRING,
    zip_code           STRING,
    state              STRING

)
PARTITION BY  (
    REGION             STRING,
    COUNTRY            STRING
)
```

Comment: This declaration is  very clear. Clarity may be the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The `partition` that we create in `hive` makes a pseudocolumn on which we can query directly without having them in create statement.

So when we include partition column on the data of the table itself(create query) we will be getting error like  `'Error in semantic analysis. Columns repeated in partitioning columns'`